# Thread: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have got one problem:
I want the method exprrasionCalculatePoints calculates in one tread and when it calculates there must be progressbar whic shows progres. When points will be calculated i draw a graph. But there is two problems, the progressbar stoped when i press on the screen not when it calculates points
Second problem is there:

```
graph = new GraphPanel(getApplicationContext());
setContentView(graph);
```

This 2 lines must execte before the one metod calculate all.
How can I fix this two problems?

Source code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                "Please wait ...", "Downloading Image ...", true);

        setContentView(R.layout.drawsurface);
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    Calculator.expr[0].exprasionCalculatePoints();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());

                }

                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

                graph = new GraphPanel(getApplicationContext());
                setContentView(graph);

            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

LogCat

```
  08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-149
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): Process: com.example.mycalc, PID: 2681
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.view.SurfaceView$1.<init>(SurfaceView.java:118)
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:118)
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at com.calculator.grap.GraphPanel.<init>(GraphPanel.java:31)
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at com.calculator.grap.GraphingTab$1.run(GraphingTab.java:58)
08-11 04:56:37.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2681):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: in android operation with window you can do only in UI thread.
Log say: you try create handler(object for transit message to UI thread) from non-UI thread.

It happened in GraphPanel constructor, case of you call it in non-UI  thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need those to run on the UI thread. Try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
            "Please wait ...", "Downloading Image ...", true);

    setContentView(R.layout.drawsurface);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                Calculator.expr[0].exprasionCalculatePoints();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());

            }

            runOnUiThread(display);


        }
    }).start();

}

Runnable display = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();

            graph = new GraphPanel(getApplicationContext());
            setContentView(graph);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

progressBar is a UI component. you cannot call it inside a thread. try using `runOnUiThread`

Comment: MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your code here
    }
});